# Can I use an existing EFI partition as /boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, backup, grub-efi

So I'm planning to switch full-time to Pop_OS! and while backing up (which is another can of worms I'll be explaining later), I realized "Wait, do I have to create a new partition for boot? Or can I use an existing one?" I didn't really know what the answer to that was so I decided, before switching to Pop_OS!, I'm gonna ask here.

**Can I use an existing EFI partition as /boot?**

Now, I'm gonna cover the second can of worms I was talking about. So while I was backing everything up, this anxiety crept in like "Is everything backed up? Can I be sure that the copy process didn't fail? HAVE I BACKED UP EVERYTHING I WANT?!" and this anxiety is keeping me from fully committing to linux. So the 2nd question of the thread is:

**How can I overcome the anxiety of whether or not I've backed up everything?**

Comment: So... this may be a dumb question, BUT.
Does Pop_OS! detect the EFI partition and mount /boot/efi there?

Comment: This site is about Ubuntu. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "This question is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow." – 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/  But I believe Pop uses SystemD boot not grub and that does put some files normally in /boot into ESP.